# Right-continuous and Progressively measurability of Lebesgue-Stieltjes integrals

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

In Karatzas&Shreve Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus P.23 Remarks 4.6: If  $A$ is an increasing process and  $X$ is progressively measurable, define the Lebesgue-Stieltjes integrals $I_{t}^{\pm}\left(\omega\right)=\int_{\left(0,t\right]}X_{s}^{\pm}\left(\omega\right)dA_{s}\left(\omega\right)$, then  $I_{t}=I_{t}^{+}-I_{t}^{-}$ is well defined and finite for all $t\geq0$, then $I$ is right-continuous and progressively measurable.

Here is the definition of an increasing process： An adapted process A is called increasing if for $P$-a.e. $\omega\in\Omega$ we have

• (a) $A_{0}\left(\omega\right)=0 $

• (b) $t\mapsto A_{t}\left(\omega\right)$ is a nondecreasing, right-continuous function,

• (c) $E\left(A_{t}\right)<\infty$ holds for every $t\in\left[0,\infty\right)$.

Now I want to show that $I$ is right-continuous and progressively measurable. It is well known that every right-continuous adapted process is progressively measurable. So I just need to show that $I$ is right-continuous and adapted. But how can I show that $I$ is right-continuous and adapted?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you also need the property that $X$ has bounded variation paths. Then right-continuity follows from
$$
\bigg| \int_{(0;t+\varepsilon]} X^+_s(\omega) \mathrm dA_s(\omega)
- \int_{(0;t]} X^+_s(\omega) \mathrm dA_s(\omega) \bigg|
\\=
\bigg| \int_{(t;t+\varepsilon]} X^+_s(\omega) \mathrm dA_s(\omega) \bigg|
\le
\int_{(t;t+\varepsilon]} X^+_s(\omega) \mathrm dA_s(\omega)
\le
\int_{(t;t+\varepsilon]} X^+_{t+\varepsilon}(\omega) \mathrm dA_s(\omega)
=
X^+_{t+\varepsilon}(\omega) (A_{t+\varepsilon}(\omega)  - A_t(\omega) )
$$
This converges to $0$ because $A$ is right-continuous and $X^+_{t+\varepsilon}(\omega) < \infty$.
Adaptedness is a little bit trickier from scratch.